# Discord JS - Remove role when reaction is added

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I should know how to do this. But the code below does not work.
The goal is to remove roles when the user adds a reaction to a message.

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  const message = await reaction.message.fetch(true);
  const channelStockSettings = '961958948976607243';
  const fundamentalPlays = '⭐️';
  const fundamentalPlaysRoleSE = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '⭐');
  const fundamentalPlaysRoleUS = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '⭐');
  const longTerm = '⛰'; 
  const longTermRoleSE = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '⛰'); 
  const longTermRoleUS = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '⛰'); 
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelStockSettings) {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === fundamentalPlays) {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(fundamentalPlaysRoleSE);
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(fundamentalPlaysRoleUS);
      } else if (reaction.emoji.name === longTerm) {
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(longTermRoleSE);
        await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(longTermRoleUS);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  });
```

This is the way I've coded this before. What the ... is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing your code, it appears that the issue is that you have the wrong unicode emotes, assuming you're trying to use the default Discord emotes for star and mountain. In other words, `reaction.emoji.name === fundamentalPlays` and `reaction.emoji.name === longTerm` both were returning false.

I'm not sure how this happened or where you got these unicode emotes from (perhaps an older version of discord, or from a third-party website?), but neither correctly matches the Discord unicode emote (the star emotes seem to look exactly the same but are not equal, and the mountain emotes both do not look the same and are not equal). The best way to get the unicode form of any Discord emote is to put a backslash before a Discord emote when sending it. Then, copy the unicode emote that it gives you.

Here's your code, modified to have the correct unicode emotes. I tested it, and it is working for me:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    console.log("Reaction received");

    const message = await reaction.message.fetch(true);
    const channelStockSettings = '883731756438671391';

    const fundamentalPlays = '⭐';
    const fundamentalPlaysRoleSE = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member');
    const fundamentalPlaysRoleUS = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Youtuber');
    const longTerm = '⛰️'; 
    const longTermRoleSE = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Testor'); 
    const longTermRoleUS = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Co-op'); 

    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if (user.bot) return;
    if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelStockSettings) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === fundamentalPlays) {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(fundamentalPlaysRoleSE);
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(fundamentalPlaysRoleUS);
        } else if (reaction.emoji.name === longTerm) {
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(longTermRoleSE);
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(longTermRoleUS);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that there could be numerous additional issues responsible for this code not working, however:
a) The `messageReactionAdd` event only fires for reactions added to cached messages. Therefore, it will not fire if you add a reaction to a message sent before the bot started. If you are trying to do this with such an uncached message, you will need to specifically fetch the message immediately when your bot starts up (most likely in your `ready` event handler).
b) Make sure you have the correct intents for receiving messages and message reactions. I assume you do, but double-check, otherwise the `messageReactionAdd` event will not fire at all.

Comment: How do I manage to come accross issues like this, lol.  I even tried to copy it in from multiple sources. Works now - thanks!

Comment: Np, this is certainly the first time I've seen this issue occur lol

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with my bot. Can you try delete the embed message and add it again. Then try it again.

Comment: Nothing happens still

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).